# MPI: scattering a matrix as distributed array

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to distribute a 3x3 matrix as 1x1 blocks over 3 processes, in a block-cyclic way -  i.e., in this case, each process receives 3 1x1 blocks, something like follows:

```
1 2 3 --> these three 1x1 blocks to proc. 0
4 5 6 --> these three 1x1 blocks to proc. 1
7 8 9 --> these three 1x1 blocks to proc. 2



(data is stored in a column-major way:)

data/position 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
process       0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
```

The final goal is to distribute matrices of arbitrary size in a block-cyclic way, but by now I am trying to stick with something basic and easier as this case, in order to learn and increase complexity afterwards as I become more confident with the problem handling.

The way I am doing this is specified in this minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <mpi.h>

MPI_Comm comm;
int size, rank;

double *distribute(double *input) {

    MPI_Datatype distributed_base, distributed_resized;

    // original matrix dimensions
    int gsize_array[2] = {3, 3};

    // distribution mode array
    int distrib_array[2] = {MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC, MPI_DISTRIBUTE_CYCLIC};

    // block dimensions
    int darg_array[2] = {1, 1};

    // process grid per dimension
    int psize_array[2] = {3, 1};

    MPI_Type_create_darray(size, rank, 2,
                           gsize_array, distrib_array,
                           darg_array, psize_array,
                           MPI_ORDER_C,
                           MPI_DOUBLE, &distributed_base);

    MPI_Type_commit(&distributed_base);

    // Now I resize the base datatype to have the proper size for each distribution
    // QUESTION - How could I get number of blocks/values that each process will receive?
    // (... via getting true extent for the datatype?)
    // Here I know that each process will receive exactly 3 doubles
    MPI_Aint lb, e;
    MPI_Type_get_true_extent(distributed_base, &lb, &e);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(distributed_base, 0, 3 * sizeof(double), &distributed_resized);
    MPI_Type_commit(&distributed_resized);

    double *output = NULL;
    output = (double *) calloc(9, sizeof(double));


    // scatter parameters:
    // input  - I expect root to scatter exactly 1 distributed_resized to each process from the input buffer
    // output - I expect that each process receives exactly 1 distributed_resized
    MPI_Scatter(input, 1, distributed_resized,
                output, 1, distributed_resized,
                0, comm);

    MPI_Type_free(&distributed_base);
    MPI_Type_free(&distributed_resized);
    return output;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rows = 3, cols = 3;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);


    double global[9] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0,
                        4.0, 5.0, 6.0,
                        7.0, 8.0, 9.0};

    double *distributed = distribute(global);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("[rank %d] %f\n", rank, distributed[i]);

    MPI_Finalize();


}
```

The expected result would be having each process with 3 1x1 blocks as said before, but the output I obtain is that only root (0) process has its data correctly distributed (print order may vary):

```
[rank 0] 1.000000
[rank 0] 2.000000
[rank 0] 3.000000
[rank 2] 0.000000
[rank 2] 0.000000
[rank 2] 0.000000
[rank 1] 0.000000
[rank 1] 0.000000
[rank 1] 0.000000
```

Am I using `MPI_Type_Create_darray` properly? I have written all my doubts as comments in the snippet.
Also, maybe I am using the wrong approach? I.e., maybe there is a better way to use MPI functions to achieve what I am trying to do?

EDIT: I run this snippet via `mpirun -n 3 --oversubscribe executable`